# Question - Differentiability of functions of several variables

Tags: limits, differential-geometry, definition

I'm currently studying some definitions of the differentiability of functions of several variables. But I have trouble understanding.

May I ask why the limit below is equal to zero?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Is it because we consider $y = y_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a *definition*. You don't prove a definition. That's how we define a differentiable function from $\Bbb R^2$ into $\Bbb R$. We could alse define a differentiable function from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$ as a function $f$ such that, for each $x_0\in\Bbb R$, there is some $a\in\Bbb R$ such that$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-a(x-x_0)}{x-x_0}=0.$$

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now!